# Blender shows exported meshes as a box

Tags: export

I have .blend file which when I open through blender, shows up like this:

[image]

Now, when I export it as .3ds, and then open it again through blender, it shows up as this:

[image]

Is this normal? Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

Open blender and go to `File>Import>.3ds` then import your file via there